# Tikz - Remove border only on one node of a matrix of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have this matrix of nodes:

```
\matrix (B) [
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={
    draw,
    minimum width=23mm,
    minimum height=10mm
  },
  inner sep=6pt,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=1cm
] at (0, 1.3) {
  Model 2.1 &
  Model 2.2 &
  Model 2.3 &
  $\cdots$
  \\
};
```

How can I remove the cell border on the node that contains `\cdots`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To affect a single node you need to be locally passing an argument to the node in question with the `|[foo]|` syntax at the beginning of the relevant matrix element which passes the argument `foo` when creating that specific node.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={
    draw,
  },
] at (0, 0) {
  A &
  B &
  C &
  |[draw=none]|
  $\cdots$
  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```